# Using webpack devserver setupMiddlewares for assets cannot be loaded from style

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

## The old webpack format used to work: before()

**webpack.oldversion.config.js**

```js
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
{
  devServer: {
    contentBase: dist,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    before: app => {
      app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(dist, '/assets')));
    }
  }
}
```

## The new webpack format does not work: setupMiddlewares

**webpack.newversion.config.js**

```js
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
{
  devServer: {
    contentBase: dist,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares,devServer) => {
      devServer.app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(dist, '/assets')));
      return middlewares;
    }
  }
}
```

The new format works only when providing the port number

**style.scss**

```css
.elem {
  background: url(localhost:3000/assets/myfile.png);
}
```

The new format DOES NOT work when just trying to load from the root

**style.scss**

```css
.elem {
  background: url(/assets/myfile.png);
}
```

I am curious why? because I don't want to hardcode localhost:3000/assets into my styles.